# Is there a tool in Linux to add an extended attribute to a file?

Tags: linux, files, xattr

The `getfattr` tool is used to get the extended attributes of a file, but is there a tool to add an extended attribute to a file?

Comment: The [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getfattr) tells you that, in the see-also section.

Comment: 'getfattr` only retrieves file ACLs, not all possible extended attributes of a file.

Comment: @fpmurphy How do you know that `getfattr` can only retrieve the file's ACLs? based on my testings, I can use it to get other extended attributes also, for example I can get the extended user attributes using this command: `getfattr -d file.txt`.

Comment: @John  Perhaps you would care to provide an example of the `-d` option displaying other extended attributes.  AFAIK, the `-d` only displays the default ACL and not any other type of extended attributes.

Comment: @fpmurphy I have used this command to set extended attributes: `setfattr -n user.hello -v world file.txt`, and this command to get extended attributes: `getfattr -d -m user file.txt`. I was successful in setting and getting the **user** and **security** and **trusted** extended attributes. But when I tried to set the **system** extended attributes, I got this error: `setfattr: file.txt: Operation not supported`, but when I tried to get the **system** extended attributes...

Comment: @fpmurphy ...I didn't get any error but I also didn't get any results (I don't know if this is because `getfattr` intentionally didn't return any results or if it's because the file doesn't have any **system** extended attributes).

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to Unix & Linux.

The `setfattr` command is the tool you’re looking for.